# Salesforce Data Extension Behavior

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

**Scenario:** 
I created an email that displays different content based on the contact's "Mailing Country". The email is sent to a Salesforce Data Extension using a Salesforce Send Email interaction.

The field "Mailing Country" is part of the Salesforce Data Extension and also an attribute on the All Subscribers list. For a recipient, the "Mailing Country" field is blank in the SFDE, but in All Subscribers, the "Mailing Country" is "United States".

When sending, would the dynamic content display based on the recipient having a blank value for "Mailing Country" in the SFDE or would content display based on the recipient having a value, say United States, for a "Mailing Country" in All Subscribers?

Answer (score 0):

In your specific usecase, it's a dynamic Content Block. That block gives you a choice:
[image]

==

Generally speaking:

You can, in any send context, use personalization strings %%nameOfMyField%% to refer back to the "data source", which by default is the data extension used for sending. Nothing different about a Salesforce DE in this regard. If you have no matching attribute (not: an empty attribute of the same name) of the name in the Data Extension, then Personalization Strings fall back to All Subscribers.

Without dynamic content, if you have the same name of a Profile Attribute and a data extension field, the data extension wins. I justed retested to confirm.

I have the profile attribute "Text" populated for a user in both Data Extension AND All Subscribers:

a) In the sendout DE it says "dataExtensiontext"

b) All Subscribers: here it says "profileText". Those fields are called Profile Attributes.

[image]

result: The message pulls in the data extension text in a preview for this DE.
[image]